# iptables: using "conntrack" and "recent" modules to block unsolicited packets

Tags: iptables, firewall, packet, netfilter

When I only allow `RELATED` and `ESTABLISHED` packets, and `DROP` everything else, my firewall rules work perfectly and I have no problems:

```
### VARIANT A
-A INPUT -i wlan0 -m conntrack   --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED       -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i wlan0                                                    -j   DROP
```

However, I want to go a step further and blacklist any `IP` which has sent me an "unsolicited" packet. I have modified my rule:

```
### VARIANT B
-A INPUT -i wlan0 -m recent --name PORTSCAN --update --seconds 3600  -j   DROP
-A INPUT -i wlan0 -m conntrack   --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED       -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i wlan0 -m recent --name PORTSCAN --set                    -j   DROP
```

The rules work like this:

```
Rule 1: checks whether IP address is already blacklisted and drops it if yes
Rule 2: allows RELATED,ESTABLISHED packets
Rule 3: all other packets which fail RELATED,ESTABLISHED test are blacklisted
```

These rules work as intended in 99,9% of cases, but only on few websites do I have problems. The Stack Exchange websites are one such example. It looks as if stackexchange.com is sending me packets, which the `conntrack` module does not recognize as related or established. Therefore, these packets do not pass `rule 2`, and are blacklisted by `rule 3`.

This happens usually when I am in the editing mode (i.e. asking a question, or editing an existing question).

In such case, I have to flush the blacklist:

```
echo / >/proc/net/xt_recent/PORTSCAN
```

and then everything works again.

There could be two explanations for this problem:

```
a) the conntrack module is deficient, in that it does not recognize
   legitimate packets as being RELATED/ESTABLISHED
b) SE websites are indeed sending unsolicited packets
```

I believe that `b` is more likely to be true, because of following reasoning:

variant A of my iptables rules drops all packets which it does not recognize as `RELATED/ESTABLISHED`. Since everything works perfectly well, these packets were not needed for my session. These were indeed unsolicited packets, which were not supposed to be sent to me in the first place.

The variant B of my iptables rules just goes a step further in that it "punishes" the offending `IP` and adds it to the blacklist.

**Q: How can I modify my iptables rules, so that it works with SE sites as well?**

I would also appreciate comments regarding my analysis of the problem

here is my related post on meta.unix.stackexchange.com:
 [stackexchange.com is sending me unsolicited packets (and consequently gets blocked by firewall)](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3282/stackexchange-com-is-sending-me-unsolicited-packets-and-consequently-gets-block)

Comment: Use IP sets (`ipset` command) if your system supports them. They're faster for block lists. Also, your definition of portscan is a bit off. A single "unsolicited" packet doesn't indicate a *port scan* at all.

Comment: @0xC0000022L - I don't claim that single unsolicited packet constitutes PORTSCAN. But my rule is primarily designed to protect against port-scanning. The name `PORTSCAN` in my example is completely irrelevant. If you don't like it, you can substitute `BLACKLIST`. But the underlying problem stays the same.

Comment: Add a `-j LOG` line before adding the IP to the blacklist, so that you can find out what packets are actually affected. I've seen that AJAX sites (like SE) can cause a browser to close an open connection prematurely, the site still sends some packets which aren't matched by `RELATED,ESTABLISHED` at that point in time.